# invalid_request post to access Token

Tags: node.js, request, access-token, invalidation

I have problem with post request authentification while trying to run the code I get error invalide request does anyone know how I could solve this problem, I get this error `{ error: 'invalid_request' }`

[image]

```js
const express = require('express');
   
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const btoa = require('btoa');
const { catchAsync } = require('./utils');
const router = express.Router();
    
const CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID ';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET';
const creds = btoa(`${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`);
const redirect = encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:50451/callback');
    
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
   res.redirect('https://flow.polar.com/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=client_id');
});

router.get('/list', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
   if (!req.query.code) throw new Error('NoCodeProvided');
      const code = req.query.code;
      const creds = btoa(`${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`);
   
      fetch('https://polarremote.com/v2/oauth2/token', {
         method: 'POST',
         data : {
            'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' : redirect,
            'code' : code
         },    
         headers : {
            'Authorization':`Basic ${creds}`,
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
             'Accept':' application/json;charset=UTF-8'
         }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
          console.log(response.json());
       }).then(function(body) {
           console.log(body); 
           res.send('POST');
       });
 })
```

Comment: `Content-type: application/json` ?.

Comment: Request headers
Authorization = Basic auth with base64 encoded string client_id:client_secret. For example, if your client id is 12345 and client sercret is verySecret, then you need to base64 encode string 12345:verySecret, resulting MTIzNDU6dmVyeVNlY3JldA==. Value of authorization header in that case should be Basic MTIzNDU6dmVyeVNlY3JldA==
Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept = application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: I meant that try to set `Content-type: application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded `

Comment: I have already tried it but it is the same problem

Comment: @info did you solve it? happening to me the same

Comment: i have the same problem, did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when I pass arguments in URI, I mean `https://polarremote.com/v2/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA`. When I use @PHP `curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA');` it works well.